# Does SE prevent false, duplicate memberships being manufactured?

Tags: support, reputation, multiple-accounts

If someone were to add another, anonymous membership, they could ask an obscure question (in the guise of the anonymous member) to which they had already researched a brilliant answer, thus enhancing the reputation of their prime account.

And they could vote up their own questions, comments and answers.

I have noticed some rather questionable situations and wondered if SE is policed sufficiently that this kind of thing would be noticed and prevented.

Comment: That's dumb. Why share? If a question and answer are *really that good* you can ask and answer yourself, getting *ALL* the credit

Comment: So _that's_ what a sockpuppet is.

Comment: “I have noticed some rather questionable situations” While this is a duplicate, in the future, feel free to provide specifics.

Comment: Don't provide specifics *here*, though! Raise a flag on one of the posts for moderator attention, and provide specifics *there*. There's no point in calling people out publicly when you only have a suspicion, and no one but moderators have access to the tools necessary to determine whether an account is fraudulent.

Comment: I will follow that. Thank you.